# getting the binary data represented by the hexadecimal string back in java vs python

Tags: java, python

I know that in python `binascii.unhexlify(initValue)`
 return the  binary data represented by the hexadecimal string back.

I am trying to convert `binascii.unhexlify(initValue)` to java.

I tried the following code lines in java but I am getting different results then the code in python:

```
 DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(value);
```

I run the following example:

my input - hexadecimal string:

```
 value = '270000f31d32d1051400000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```

when running in python:

```
 result = binascii.unhexlify(value)
```

I am getting:

```
    result = "'\x00\x00\xf3\x1d2\xd1\x05\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
```

when running in java:

```
 byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(value);
```

I am getting:

```
   bytes = [39, 0, 0, -13, 29, 50, -47, 5, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

1.why I am getting different results?

2. why do I get the output in python with '\' marks?

Comment: were you able to achieve this? Answer given below by @chx3 is giving response but bytes looks different as generates in Java. Did you find any other way to get similar output?

Answer (score 2):

The first hex of your result, "'" is exactly 39 in signed char. In python, you can use built-in function ord("'") to get 39.
You can probably get what you want in this python code

```
value = '270000f31d32d1051400000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000'
result = binascii.unhexlify(value)
bytes = [ord(x) for x in result]
```

You will be getting this unsigned char:

```
[39, 0, 0, 243, 29, 50, 209, 5, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```